# How to get express route to go through passport for authentification

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt, passport-jwt

I'm recently changing a boilerplate I made in es6 to a slightly older version es5. I had to recreate the export, require instead of using imports and the routing is functional now.

I have a structure like this:

```
index.js (app)
api/index.js (/api endpoint)
api/auth.js (/api/auth endpoint)
api/protected.js (/api/protected endpoint)
```

In my auth route I have the login and register functionning and generating a token:

```
const token = jwt.sign({id: req.body.username},  config.jwtSecret)
```

In my protected.js I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('../config/passport');
router.use(passport.initialize({ session: false }));
router.use(passport.session());
router.get('/test', passport.authenticate('jwt') , (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello sweetie', auth: req.isAuthenticated(), user: req.session.passport.user})
});
module.exports = router;
```

And in my passport.js

```
const
  passport = require('passport'),
  config = require('./../config'),
  passportJwt = require('passport-jwt'),
  JwtStrategy = passportJwt.Strategy,
  ExtractJwt = passportJwt.ExtractJwt,
  userSchema = require('./../schemas/userSchema');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    done(null, user[0].username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
    console.log('DESER -- '+username);
    userSchema.checkUsername(username)
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user[0]);
        done(null, user[0]);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
});

const jwtOptions = {
    secretOrKey: config.jwtSecret,
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
}

passport.use('jwt', new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    console.log('Strategy: '+ jwt_payload.id);
    userSchema.checkUsername(jwt_payload.id)
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user[0].username);
        if(user[0]) return done(null, user)
        else return done(null, false)
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

The problem is when I try to access: 127.0.0.1:8080/api/protected/test
with the token I got on login it give me a: `Unauthorized`

Furthermore the `console.log` inside the:

- serializeUser
- deserializeUser
- jwt Strategy

Are never shown and thus I think the passport middleware isn't used.

How could I get the `/protected` routes to use the passport middleware?

Edit: I have tried printing the passport object and I can see my `jwt` strategy is indeed defined. So I don't see why it doesn't want to go through it.

[image: There si a strategy]

Comment: Are you sending the jwtToken in header?

Comment: @WaqasNoor yes I am sending it as I try the request with Postman

Comment: replace ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization') with ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() and send your token in postman 
Authorization: bearer your_jwt_token

Comment: @WaqasNoor Thanks works perfevt just modifying the Extract. write an answer and some explanation if you dont mind so i can accept it and give you the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your passport is looking for `authorization` header not `Authorization` header.

Change your

`jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization')`

to

`ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()`

so your options will look like

```
const jwtOptions = {
    secretOrKey: config.jwtSecret,
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
}
```

Now what this does is passport will look for `Authorization` header with value `bearer your_jwt_token`.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt